# Select child of input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a quiz website. Each quiz has a form which contains the questions (a div). Each question contains the options (a radio input, generated from a Flask for loop).

```
<div class="question">
    {{squestions[question]}}
    <br><br>
    <div class="options">
        {% for opt in opts[question] %}
            <input type="radio" class="option" name="{{question}}" value="{{opt.answerId}}">
                <a>{{opt.answer}}</a>
            </input>
            <br>
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to show the user which answer is correct (after they select something). I thought this could be possible by iterating through each child of the question and coloring them appropriately (green if right, red if wrong) as such:

```
$("input[name=" + question + "]").children().each(function(i) {
    if (correct == $(this).text) {
        $(this).css('color', 'green');
    } else {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

However, the children selector is returning `[prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]` objects. My intention was for it to return the `<a>` objects.

I don't think the problem is caused by the for loop because when the document is ready it has already generated all the elements.

Comment: can you add the rendered HTML in OP

Comment: Input elements can't have children. They're self-closing, there's no `</input>`

Comment: the rendered html?

Comment: @Barmar Why did you comment when that's the answer? Please post it as an answer. Or I will.

Comment: @ErikE It explains why his code doesn't work, it doesn't solve the problem. He needs to redesign his form.

Comment: @Barmar I think that's a new question! :)

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. I changed .children() to .parent().children() and it works.

Comment: `$(this).text` is a function, edit it to `$(this).text()`

Comment: @diavolic Thank you, but that's not my actual code, I just changed it for readability since the actual code has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input>` elements can't have children. The answer text should be after the radio button, not a child of it.

```
<div class="question">
    {{squestions[question]}}
    <br><br>
    <div class="options">
        {% for opt in opts[question] %}
            <input type="radio" class="option" name="{{question}}" value="{{opt.answerId}}">
            <a>{{opt.answer}}</a>
            <br>
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then your code can use `.next()` to get the answer element. Also, `.text` is a function, you need to call it with `()`.

```
$("input[name=" + question + "]").next('a').each(function(i) {
    if (correct == $(this).text()) {
        $(this).css('color', 'green');
    } else {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```